# Grouping SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, grouping

I have asked this before but not got 100% the answer I am looking for so I am hoping to explain this better.

I am creating an SSRS report with multiple datasets but they will all have in common a Customer. I want to setup a report that will be one big report but break down graphs and tables by customer. Example:

```
Customer A

X Logged Incidents (chart)
X Logged Service Requests (chart)
X Logged Problems(chart)

Customer B
X Logged Incidents (chart)
X Logged Service Requests (chart)
X Logged Problems (chart)
```

I have tried doing a table filter and also a list view both of which do not work.

Comment: Unfortunately you have not explained this well enough.  We need examples of expected output, specifics on what you have tried, exact issues you are having etc.

Comment: It would probably be better to do all the grouping in your source proc. This reduces the complexity of the report.

Comment: Hello- I thought I might of explained it enough. But we need basically one report containing several pages but 1 or 2 pages with the specific information related to that customer. We currently do this but we use a filter on the report so we can just filter on the one customer but we want it to show on one page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a report (maybe base this on your existing report) that accepts the customerID as a parameter. Get that working so it shows your three charts.
2. Next, create another report.
3. In this report, add a dataset (lets call it dsCustomerlist for clarity) that returns a list of all your customers that you want to show in your report.
4. Add a table with a single column on the report design surface.
5. Set the dataset property of the table to the dataset containing your customer list (dsCustomerlist).
6. In the table cell, insert a subreport and set the subreport to be the report you created in step 1
7. In the subreport parameters, set the customerID parameter to the customerID column from your dataset (dsCustomerlist).

You'll probably want to add page break and such to tidy it up, but that should give you a start.